# Solve Equation $3^x=2+3^{-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Using the substitution $u=3^x$, or otherwise, solve, correct to 3 significant figures, the equation 
>   $3^x=2+3^{-x}$

My attempt:

$u=2+u^{-1}$

$u-u^{-1}=2$

$ {{u^2-1}\over {u}}=2$

$\log ({{u^2-1}\over {u}})=\log (2)$

$\log ({u^2-1}) - \log ({u}) =\log (2)$

$\log ({(u-1)(u+1)}) -\log (u) = \log (2)$

$\log {(u-1)} + \log {(u+1)} -\log (u)= \log (2)$

Then what can I do please ?

Comment: The third line is a quadratic, and can be solved as such.  I wouldn't pull out the logarithm unless you see some variables in the exponent.

Comment: There was no reason to invoke the logarithm, as the equation has been rationalized (I mean $u=2+u^{-1}$, which you rewrite $u^2=2u+1$).

Comment: Think of what equations you previously know how to solve and try and turn it into such an equation.

Comment: Before taking logs, note that $$u=\frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4--4}}{2}\, \quad \iff u=\ldots$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you get to 
$$\frac{u^2-1}{u}=2,$$
note that it can be solved as a quadratic equation:
$$u^2-1=2u.$$
Solve it for $u$ as usual: $u=whatever$.

Finally, substitute back $u = 3^x$ and take logarithms: $3^x=whatever$, so that $x=\log_3(whatever)$.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand  :), the answer $u=1+\sqrt 2$ and $u=1-\sqrt 2$ so $3^x=1+\sqrt 2$ and by take $log$ we got $x=0.802$.

Comment: @Dima That's it! Since $1-\sqrt{2}<0$, you can only have $3^x=1+\sqrt{2}$. By the way, if you think that any of the answers is good enough for you, consider accepting it, so that other users can benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to see the $\sinh$ function :
$$3^x-3^{-x} =2 \sinh(x\ln(3)) = 2$$
So you get :
$$x = \frac{\operatorname{arcsinh}(1)}{\ln(3)}= \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{1+1^2})}{\ln(3)} = \frac{\ln(1+\sqrt{2})}{\ln(3)}$$

Comment: Creative, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: multiply everything by $3^x$, make the substitution and then it will became an equation of second degrees.

Comment: the OP substituted already 3^x by u.